# What determines an assist medal in Warhammer 40,000 Space Marine

Tags: warhammer-40k-space-marine

The process of awarding an assist medal seems to me to be a bit random/buggy.

For example I could remove an enemy's armour and part of their health and then a teammate would take the kill, but I will not be awarded the assist medal. In other cases I have literally shot a single bullet into the enemy and have been awarded an assist medal once the enemy in question had died. This leaves me both confused an annoyed.

Does anyone know the exact criteria the game uses to award assist medals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've also noticed this, and usally it seems to happen when there are more than 2 people attacking the same enemy.

My guess would be that only the killer and the last person to hit the enemy get the awards.

Eg. with 3 players (p1, p2, p3) shooting at an enemy(e1):
p1 shoots e1 a lot
p2 then get one hit with a bolter pistol
p3 kills e1

then I think only p2 gets the assist award.

this could be tested in a private match, if you have enough friends and people are willing to test it.